# Multiple rules files in prometheus for each targets

Tags: prometheus

I have configured some node in json different-e file based on categorized. & integrated with Prometheus.yml file. i want to use rules.yml with respective json not for global.

***Here below is my prometheus.yml code***

```yaml
# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
   - "/etc/prometheus/rules.yml"
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"



  - job_name: 'Prometheus Node Exporter'
    scheme: https
**// i want to use seprate rules.yml file for this specific node_exp.json file
   tls_config:
      ca_file: node_exporter.crt
      insecure_skip_verify: true
    file_sd_configs:
      - files:
        - node_exp.json
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't specify rules for some jobs by putting them in that jobs segment.

But you can add label filter to metrics used in your rules.

For example:

```yaml
groups:
  - name: example
    rules:
    - record: code:prometheus_http_requests_total:sum
      expr: sum by (code) (prometheus_http_requests_total{job="Prometheus Node Exporter"})
```

will calculate `code:prometheus_http_requests_total:sum` only for metrics `prometheus_http_requests_total` scraped by job `Prometheus Node Exporter`